# php generated link style not working correctly

Tags: php, html, browser, hyperlink, cross-browser

Currently this code generates a colored hyperlink to an ad listing on my site.  The problem is that the text is BLACK when viewing in Firefox and Chrome.  It only seems to display the colored text in IE.

Can anyone please help me to make this work properly?

```
<a href="<?=ProdURL($rslt["offer_adsid"])?>" style="font-size:13px;"<?=$trColor?> ><?=$Lname?></a>
```

update:

here's the HTML being generated.  THANKS!

```
<a href="116-iphone-3g-8gb-as-is.htm" style="font-size:13px;"style="color:#FF0000;" >iPhone 3G 8GB AS IS</a
```

FIX!

I was able to fix this by finding where the value of $trColor is defined, then adding the font size style tag to be included along with the color style tag.  Fixed now, thanks guys!

Comment: You need to provide more information.  An example of the value  `ProdURL` returns could be relevant, but even more critical is providing an example of the value of `$trColor`

Comment: What is the *actual* resolved html that is being rendered?

Comment: 1) You should not use php short tags.  Use the full tags: `<?php`.  2) You are closing the quote after the style, but before the `$trColor` variable.  Is `$trColor` supposed to be WITHIN the style?

Comment: PHP doesnot control clientside presentation.. So your perspective of asking this question saying your problem is caused due to PHP is totally pointless. Also to be able to point out the error that is causing those link not to work in your browser, we would need something that a browser would understand.. The HTML that this piece of code is generating.

Comment: Sorry guys I'm not a programmer, trying to fix issues my developer caused.  Here's the HTML it's generating: <a href="116-iphone-3g-8gb-as-is.htm" style="font-size:13px;"style="color:#FF0000;" >iPhone 3G 8GB AS IS</a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for giving the exact HTML output.  I see two potential problems:

1. There is no space before the second `style=` element.  I'm guessing IE interprets this okay anyway, and the other browsers treat it as garbage and ignore it.
2. I'm not sure if there's an agreed-upon standard among the different mainline browsers of what to do when there are multiple `style="..."` attributes on a single HTML element.  I haven't tried it, but immediate questions that come to my mind are: Should they be additive?  Or should one of them overrule the other one?  I've always known the "correct" method to be combining all CSS directives into one `style="..."` attribute, which you could easily do here.

I would make `$trColor` be just the hexadecimal color code, and rewrite the HTML like this:

```
style="font-size:13px;color:<?php echo $trColor ?>"
```

So that your HTML is rendered like so:

```
<a href="116-iphone-3g-8gb-as-is.htm" style="font-size:13px;color:#FF0000">iPhone 3G 8GB AS IS</a>
```

Comment: <a href="116-iphone-3g-8gb-as-is.htm" style="font-size:13px;"style="color:#FF0000;" >iPhone 3G 8GB AS IS</a>

Comment: Thanks.  I've updated my answer now that I can see what the HTML comes out to be.

Comment: I was able to fix this by finding where the value of $trColor is defined, then adding the font size style tag to be included along with the color style tag. Fixed now, thanks guys!

Comment: @user1437646 I strongly recommend you follow Curtisdf's answer more closely and have $trColor only contain the actual color value, while hard-coding the rest of the tag.  You're setting yourself up for a maintenance nightmare otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is in `$trColor` however you could do this:

```
...style="font-size:13px;color:<?php echo $trColor?>"...
```

if $trColor contains a color code that works with CSS like `#FFFFFF` or `white` for example.

Comment: it does this "style="color:#FF0000;"

Comment: How did that extra quote get in there?

Comment: My bad.  here's the entire output:  <a href="116-iphone-3g-8gb-as-is.htm" style="font-size:13px;"style="color:#FF0000;" >iPhone 3G 8GB AS IS</a>

Comment: Is there any way you can have $trColor only contain the color?  `#FF0000`

Comment: I was able to fix this by finding where the value of $trColor is defined, then adding the font size style tag to be included along with the color style tag.  Fixed now, thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="<? echo ProdURL($rslt['offer_adsid'])?>" style="font-size:13px;color=<?=$trColor?>;"><?=$Lname?></a>
```